# selecting all sundays between given range in ssrs dimension filter using mdx

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I need to select only dates which are Sundays from date dimension in ssrs using MDX where the dimension hierarchy is [date][date-date]. How can I do this ?

Comment: we need more information to answer this question - a screenprint of the structure of your date dimension will definitely help.

Comment: Suppose we have a date dimension which is

Comment: most cubes have a date dimension - most date dimensions are different - what does yours look like?  Danylo has guessed you have this hierarchy included `[Date].[WeekDay]` but you might not have this

Answer (score 0):

Simply using a crossjoin:

```
select 
    {} on 0,
    [Date].[WeekDay].&[6] * [Date].[Day].[Day].Members on 1
from [YourCube]
```